# KML labels not appearing in Google Map API

Tags: api, dictionary, label, kml

I have created a kml with LabelStyle showing Label size and labelcolor.
If I open google maps and import the kml the labels appear, however if I use the api and link to the kml. the markers appear but without the label. Is this a limitation of the api or am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

`<LabelStyle>` is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API v3

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements):

| KML element | Supported in the API? |
| --- | --- |
| `<LabelStyle>` | no |

Comment: Thanks, must have missed that,I was looking!